# Connect to internet on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: networking, ethernet

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 14.10 on my HP Pavilion. I try to connect to internet by wired connection but Ubuntu doesn’t recognize the Ethernet card.

When I follow the instructions at:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2455972/how-to-fix-your-internet-connection-in-ubuntu-linux.html

First it says that the "Cable unplugged" for Wired connection - although the cable is connected- also the button "save" still closed even after editing manually the IPv4 Settings.

Best.

Here is the output of lspci

```
safi@safi:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 
(rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA 
Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) Thermal Subsystem (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98M [GeForce 9200M GS] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
06:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller
06:00.1 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller
06:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller
06:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller
06:00.4 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller
```

Here is what it says at each command:

```
safi@safi:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dkms

safi@safi:~$ wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.038.00-1_all.deb
--2015-03-15 18:17:12--  http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.038.00-1_all.deb
Resolving ftp.de.debian.org (ftp.de.debian.org)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘ftp.de.debian.org’

safi@safi:~$ sudo dpkg -i r8168*.deb
dpkg: error processing archive r8168*.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 r8168*.deb

safi@safi:~$ echo "blacklist r8169" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8169.conf
blacklist r8169

safi@safi:~$ sudo modprobe -rfv r8169
rmmod r8169
rmmod mii

safi@safi:~$ sudo modprobe -v r8168
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8168 not found.
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `lspci` command?

Comment: 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)

Comment: Please, **edit** your question and paste the code **in** the question.

Comment: Here is a part of, the whole output the site here says too long characters ..                                             00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)

Comment: I've never had a software problem with that family of Realtek Ethernet controller. "Cable unplugged" usually means exactly that, but sometimes the cable has a short in it (replace it) or there's a bent pin in one of the sockets (check both system and router port).

Comment: Sorry, there is a misunderstanding. **The commands of my response are for executing when connected to internet.** If you don't have ethernet nor wifi, notify me it and I'll edit my answer to cover that case

Comment: Yes I have not internet access on Ubuntu right now, either via Ethernet nor wifi ..  Thanx

Comment: Try now, I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

- First configure the wifi to work with these steps:

  - Insert your installation media (your LiveCD/LiveUSB)
  - Open the LiveCD/LiveUSB.
  - Navigate to `pool` --> `main` --> `b` --> `b43-fwcutter`
  - Double click on the `.deb` file and install it.
  - Reboot
- Then try to configure ethernet with these commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
  wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.038.00-1_all.deb
  sudo dpkg -i r8168*.deb
  echo "blacklist r8169" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8169.conf
  sudo modprobe -rfv r8169
  sudo modprobe -v r8168
  sudo service network-manager restart
  ```

Your ethernet card seems to be the only Realtek card not supported.